# Div extends beyond screen

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Goodevening!

My problem is fairly simply, my div extends beyond the screen.
I have this div:

```
<div id="button">Button-text</div>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
#button {
    background-color: grey;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:15px;
    width:100%;
}
```

I could solve it with box-sizing(but that won't work on older browsers), and it have to be responsive. Any solutions?

I also have set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2k9Cd/

Comment: So the padding, margin and width 100% that are causing the extension have to stay?

Comment: It has to have the padding, margin, and fill the whole screen. I have been trying to accomplish that by using a parent div to keep the inner trapped, but it kept extending beyond.

Comment: Try to add a parent div with a **fixed** width.

Comment: If you add the container parent div you have to lose the width: 100% of the inner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, use % for margins and padding.

```
#button {
    background-color: grey;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2%;
    margin:3%;
    width:90%;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k9Cd/2/)

Note: width (%) = 100% - [2 x margin(%)] - [2 x padding(%)]. In this case that is 90%=100%-2x3%-2x2%

Comment: This is difinitely the most elegant solutions!

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
#button {
    background-color: grey;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:15px;
}
#container {
    background-color: black;
    width:100%;
}
```

Html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="button">Button-text</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k9Cd/3/)

Comment: Wow! I did this like three times.. But hey! This works appearently!

Comment: You probably left out `width: 100%` in the button style, at least that is what I did :)

Answer (score 0):

`margin:15px auto; padding:10px; width:95%;
 width:calc(100%-20px);`

This will take the width and reduce it for the padding.

Comment: But OP is concerned about older browsers.

Comment: in which case, margin:15px auto; padding:10px; width:95%; width:calc(100%-20px);